# How to add class or HTML attribute to "Read more" button?

Tags: php, woocommerce

On overview page products out of stock have a button "read more". I changed the text to "Out of Stock" but I want to make it impossible to click. It now links to an Out-of-stock page.

Function `Public function add_to_cart_text(){...}` needs the HTML attribute `disabled` when text is "read more", or a CSS class whenever it's out of stock. I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Have you looked into the [jQuery css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) functionality?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it, is to overwrite the function which adds the add-to-cart button, and check if the product is in stock or not

if it is not, then use a custom template for the button...

Hard to explain, easier to do.

```
/**
 * Hide loop read more buttons for out of stock items 
*/
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
        global $product; // Getting the product data.
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ){
           //The product is not in stock, or is not purchasable, use your custom template here.
           wc_get_template('loop/yourCustomTemplateWithDisabledBtnHere.php');
        } else {
           //everything is normal.
           wc_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
        } 
        
    }
}
```

Or, create the necessary folders and files in your child theme, as according to woocommerce docs, and change the add-to-cart.php file, to accommodate your functionality - like adding disabled to out of stock items - This is probably a simpler way, since you also need to create the folders and files in the method above.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will look into this but im very scared to hurt the plugin installation, i have zero experience fiddling like this. Is there any easy to understand documentation regarding the folders and files structure?

In your code i see the yourcustomtemplate....php, for instance. I have no clue what to put into that file hence im asking for documentation.. Im sorry

Comment: you don't overwrite the plugin files - There is an explnation on how to overwrtite each template file, in all the files inside woocommerce templates. like f.x `//This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.`

Comment: I have been trying to do anything but i cant get it to work. Im getting just a bunch of errors and nothing works... I have also tried injecting some jquery which looks for the text i have in the button and than gives the parent a class with no point events. The class itself works via element inspector, but i cant get it assigned. This is so infuriating